# How to annotate the result documents with a count of child documents?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of categories, each category document containing a link to its parent (except  the root categories). Pretty simple so far.

I want to list the categories, and add a `subcategory_count` field to every document with the count of direct descendants.

How should I go about doing this? Could Map/Reduce be of use?

Comment: btw why don't you store all of them in a single document if you're already listing all of them?

Comment: Because that would complicate the schema too much and make tree changes more difficult programmatically... Also, it might get over 16MB very fast.

Answer (score 1):

There are no "calculated columns" in MongoDB, so you can't select data and count subdocuments at the same time.

This is also the reason why most people store array length along with the array.

```
{friends_list: [1, 3, 234, 555],
 friends_count: 4}
```

This helps for easier retrieval, filtering, sorting, etc. But it requires a little bit more of manual work.

So, you are basically limited to these options:

1. Store everything in one document.
2. Store subcategory count in the category.
3. Count subcategories on the client-side.

Comment: I guess I'd go with option #2 for now.

Comment: After more research, I decided to go with the MPTT storage algorithm - it allows for easy calculation of descendant count (among other useful features)

Answer (score 0):

`find()` to get all of them, count the number of subcategories on each level and then update().

But it seems like your domain object should be doing this for you, so you end up with one category object that can contain categories (which could also contain categories...), and hence one mongodb document (you're listing all of them anyway, so it makes sense to retrive the whole thing in one query).

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I don't want to add another field to the category documents, but to annotate each document with the count *on the fly*.

Comment: again, my answer would be "domain object functionality". but i would add them as a field, just because its simpler and you'll end up with fewer bugs.